# Get sum of cart quantity of all options for a configurable product on cart page

Tags: configurable-product, cart, quote, quantity

I want to get sum of qty of all variations present in cart for a configurable product. For ex.- see below image--

[image]

'WHEY PROTEIN ISOLATE-WPI' is a configuration product. In cart it has 2 different variations with qty 1 and 2.

I want to get its total qty i.e 3 (1+2) on same page (cart page), how can I get it.

Although I can do it by looping for each item in cart but it will slow down the cart page, so if any one can suggest another way to do it.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this `without looping through the cart items`.

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$_item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
$qty = $_item->getQty();
```

Comment: it is showing error - Fatal error: Call to a member function getQty() on a non-object

Comment: You are sending the $product object to getItemByProduct() right?

Comment: yes, correct. you are right.

Comment: I have placed this code in cart.phtml file. Is it correct. ?

Comment: It doesnt matter where you place the code. It just needs the quote object and product object.

Comment: yes..quote object is there

Comment: Can you try to do `var_dump($_item);` after `$_item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);` this line. And check what it returns.

Comment: Because the function is there inside this class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`. `getItemByProduct()`. Now it might be returning `false` because of this line `$item->representProduct($product)`. Please check there.

Comment: `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` has the `representProduct()`.

Comment: Hope you get the whole idea there.